# Makita cordless circular saw DSS611

Tags: electrical

My Makita cordless saw has stopped working. I have replaced the brushes and armature. With the brushes removed I have 19V at the holders. With the brushes inserted and in contact with the new armature the reading is 22mv. I am not an electrical engineer so I do not know if this reading is correct. There is no hum or suggestion that the armature will turn.Regards Gordon Clamp

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing this is off-topic here, but more info might help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Much though I like to fix things (and recently brought a vacuum cleaner back to life that presumably left the factory with the dent in its brush holder that stopped it running, that I was able to un-dent and clean up so it worked again) your error, IMHO, was not binning the tool and buying a new one at the point where new brushes didn't fix it. I don't know how much you have spent, but I know that I don't consider replacing the armature cost effective on my circular saw, .vs. getting a whole new (or used) one that works. As it happens, I spent $15 on a used one...

Comment: It could be the battery under load is bad or the switch I check those prior to replacing an armature.

Comment: Hi Ed, tried several batteries that work on my other Makita tools also I assume the switch is ok as it shows on and off on my meter. I would normally agree with you Ecnerwal, I already have a brushless Makita saw, I purchased the one in question with an angle grinder and battery as a job lot. I was after the angle grinder, I am just trying to get the saw going as a hobby. Regards Gordon